# inserting values in to SqlLite database. Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am learning android development through video tutorials.

using the idea in the tutorial. I have created my own class, the database handler (Dbhandler.java) file and the (kovil.java) file. these files are working perfectly.

my aim is to add values to the database table. once the main activity (mainactivity.java) loads. i want to know how to add values to the table in mainactivity.java file on create event for my code.

can any one help me. Thank you..

here are my codes..

**Dbhandler.java file**

```
        package lk.adspace.jaffnadb;

        import java.util.ArrayList;


        import android.content.ContentValues;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
        import android.util.Log;

        public class Dbhandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {


            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

            // Database Name
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jaffnatempletest";

            // Temple table name
            private static final String TABLE_TEMPLE = "templ";


            // Contacts Table Columns names
            private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
            private static final String KEY_TMPNAME = "temple_name";
            private static final String KEY_TMPTYPE = "temple_type";
            private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
            private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
            private static final String KEY_IMGNAME = "image_name";
            private static final String KEY_YEARBUILD = "year_build";
            private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
            private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
            private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
            private static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
            private static final String KEY_TEL1 = "telephone1";
            private static final String KEY_TEL2 = "telephone2";
            private static final String KEY_DESCRI = "Description";
            private final ArrayList<kovil> temple_list = new ArrayList<kovil>();


            public Dbhandler (Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }



            // Creating Tables
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_TEMPLE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEMPLE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + KEY_TMPNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TMPTYPE + " TEXT," + KEY_LATITUDE + " TEXT," + KEY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMGNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_YEARBUILD + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_WEB + " TEXT," + KEY_TEL1 + " TEXT," + KEY_TEL2 + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DESCRI + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TEMPLE_TABLE);
            }


            // Upgrading database
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEMPLE);

            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);
            }



            // Adding new temple
            public void Add_Temple(kovil Kovil) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(KEY_TMPNAME, Kovil.gettemplename()); 
            values.put(KEY_TMPTYPE, Kovil.gettempletype()); 
            values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, Kovil.getlatitude()); 
            values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, Kovil.getlongitude()); 
            values.put(KEY_IMGNAME, Kovil.getimage_name()); 
            values.put(KEY_YEARBUILD, Kovil.getyear_build()); 
            values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, Kovil.getaddress()); 
            values.put(KEY_CITY, Kovil.getcity()); 
            values.put(KEY_EMAIL, Kovil.getemail()); 
            values.put(KEY_WEB, Kovil.getwebsite()); 
            values.put(KEY_TEL1, Kovil.gettelephone1()); 
            values.put(KEY_TEL2, Kovil.gettelephone2());
            values.put(KEY_DESCRI, Kovil.getDescription());

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_TEMPLE, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
            }






            // Getting single contact
            kovil Get_Temple(int id) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TEMPLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_TMPNAME, KEY_TMPTYPE, KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE, KEY_IMGNAME, KEY_YEARBUILD, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_CITY, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_WEB, KEY_TEL1, KEY_TEL2, KEY_DESCRI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            kovil Kovil = new kovil(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13));
            // return contact
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            return Kovil;
            }





            // Getting All Contacts
            public ArrayList<kovil> Get_Temple() {
            try {
                temple_list.clear();

                // Select All Query
                String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEMPLE;

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                // looping through all rows and adding to list
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    kovil Kovil = new kovil();
                    Kovil.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    Kovil.settemplename(cursor.getString(1)); 
                    Kovil.settempletype(cursor.getString(2)); 
                    Kovil.setlatitude(cursor.getString(3)); 
                    Kovil.setlongitude(cursor.getString(4)); 
                    Kovil.setimage_name(cursor.getString(5)); 
                    Kovil.setyear_build(cursor.getString(6)); 
                    Kovil.setaddress(cursor.getString(7)); 
                    Kovil.setcity(cursor.getString(8)); 
                    Kovil.setemail(cursor.getString(9)); 
                    Kovil.setwebsite(cursor.getString(10)); 
                    Kovil.settelephone1(cursor.getString(11)); 
                    Kovil.settelephone2(cursor.getString(12));
                    Kovil.setDescription(cursor.getString(13));



                    // Adding contact to list
                    temple_list.add(Kovil);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                // return contact list
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return temple_list;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("all_temples", "" + e);
            }

            return temple_list;
            }



        }
```

**Kovil.java File**

```
        package lk.adspace.jaffnadb;

        public class kovil {

            //public variables
            public int _id;
            public String _temple_name;
            public String _temple_type;
            public String _latitude;
            public String _longitude;
            public String _image_name;
            public String _year_build;
            public String _address;
            public String _city;
            public String _email;
            public String _website;
            public String _telephone1;
            public String _telephone2;
            public String _Description;

            //empty constructor
            public kovil (){

            }


            // int id, String temple_name, String temple_type, String latitude,  String longitude, String image_name, String year_build, String address, String city, String email, String website, String telephone1, String telephone2,  String Description


            public kovil(int id, String temple_name, String temple_type, String latitude,  String longitude, String image_name, String year_build, String address, 
                    String city, String email, String website, String telephone1, String telephone2,  String Description) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub



                  this._id= id;
                  this._temple_name=temple_name;
                  this._temple_type=temple_type;
                  this._latitude=latitude;
                  this._longitude=longitude;
                  this._image_name=image_name;
                  this._year_build=year_build;
                  this._address=address;
                  this._city=city;
                  this._email=email;
                  this._website=website;
                  this._telephone1=telephone1;
                  this._telephone2=telephone2;
                  this._Description=Description;

            }


                    public int getID() {
                    return this._id;
                    }


                    public void setID(int id) {
                    this._id = id;
                    }


                    public String gettemplename() {
                    return this._temple_name;
                    }


                    public void settemplename(String temple_name) {
                    this._temple_name=temple_name;
                    }

                    public String gettempletype() {
                    return this._temple_type;
                    }


                    public void settempletype(String temple_type) {
                    this._temple_type=temple_type;
                    }

                    public String getlatitude() {
                    return this._latitude;
                    }


                    public void setlatitude(String latitude) {
                        this._latitude=latitude;
                    }

                    public String getlongitude() {
                    return this._longitude;
                    }


                    public void setlongitude(String longitude) {
                        this._longitude=longitude;
                    }


                    public String getimage_name() {
                    return this._image_name;
                    }


                    public void setimage_name(String image_name) {
                        this._image_name=image_name;
                    }

                    public String getyear_build() {
                    return this._year_build;
                    }


                    public void setyear_build(String year_build) {
                        this._year_build=year_build;
                    }


                    public String getaddress() {
                    return this._address;
                    }


                    public void setaddress(String address) {
                        this._address=address;
                    }

                    public String getcity() {
                    return this._city;
                    }


                    public void setcity(String city) {
                        this._city=city;
                    }


                    public String getemail() {
                    return this._email;
                    }


                    public void setemail(String email) {
                        this._email=email;
                    }


                    public String getwebsite() {
                    return this._website;
                    }


                    public void setwebsite(String website) {
                        this._website=website;
                    }


                    public String gettelephone1() {
                    return this._telephone1;
                    }


                    public void settelephone1(String telephone1) {
                        this._telephone1=telephone1;
                    }

                    public String gettelephone2() {
                    return this._telephone2;
                    }


                    public void settelephone2(String telephone2) {
                        this._telephone2=telephone2;
                    }


                    public String getDescription() {
                    return this._Description;
                    }


                    public void setDescription(String Description) {
                        this._Description=Description;
                    }


        }
```

**MainActivity.java file**

```
        package lk.adspace.jaffnadb;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.Menu;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {


            Dbhandler dbhand = new Dbhandler(this); 



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);







            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: i want to add values in to the table "templ". when the application loads its main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already created your Database, Table with insert method. Then whats the problem in inserting.

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            //Define and initialize your kovil constructor with appropriate arguments.
            kovil insertData = new kovil(your_id, temple_name, temple_type, latitude,  longitude, image_name, year_build, address, 
                city, email, website, telephone1, telephone2,  Description);
            Dbhandler dbhand = new Dbhandler(this); 
            dbhand .Add_Temple(insertData );
         }
```

Comment: Thank you.. Ranjit pati.

Answer (score 1):

Call this inside you MainActivity.java

```
    Dbhandler dbhand;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       dbhand=new Dbhandler(this);

       //initialize your Kovil object here
       dbhand.addTempler(myKovelObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `dbhand.Add_Temple(Kovil)` in your `onCreate` method, where `Kovil` is the variable you want to store on the database.